# Add VAT module prestashop

Tags: javascript, prestashop

I need help, I have a module in prestashop, for the products.
Now it shows me the price of the unit and the total of the quantity chosen.

I also need to show the total price with VAT included. I can not do it.

I add code .tpl

(Total )

```
                <div class="preu_total_IVA"> <span class="text_preu_IVA">IVA incluido:</span> <span id="mp_total_price_IVA"></span> <span style="font-weight:normal;">€</span></div>
```

I add code .tpl

```
{

            var price = jsonData['price'];
            var unitprice = jsonData['unitprice'];
            var preutotaliva = jsonData['preutotaliva'];
            //var stringtotal = unitprice + '<br/><span class="mp_our_price">(Total '+price+')</span>';
            var stringtotal = price;
            $('#our_price_display').html(stringtotal);
            if($('.mp_total_price').length)
                $('.mp_total_price').html(price);
            if($('.mp_unit_price').length){ 
                $('.mp_unit_price').html(unitprice);
                if($('.mp_total_price_IVA').length)
             $('.mp_total_price_IVA').html(preutotaliva);

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, maybe I do not explain myself well, what I need is that depending on the price of the product, I calculate the VAT.

This is brought by prestashop, but I do not use prestashop for product page.
I use a module that calculates the price x unit and the total price without VAT, what I need is that I calculate with VAT.

This is what I have of the module in javascript.

```js
var price = jsonData['price'];
    var unitprice = jsonData['unitprice'];
    //var stringtotal = unitprice + '<br/><span class="mp_our_price">(Total '+price+')</span>';
    var stringtotal = price
    $('#our_price_display').html(stringtotal);
    if($('.mp_total_price').length)
     $('.mp_total_price').html(price);
    if($('.mp_unit_price').length){ 
     $('.mp_unit_price').html(unitprice);
    }
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused (missing closing tag after 'var stringtotal = price' by the way...) but... can you provide me with a link? And if you want to DISPLAY the price in the page including VAT, i think you should be changing the modules tpl file iinstead of the .js.